# Displaying a range of dates without input

Tags: mysql

E.G. - If today is Wednesday, then I can display all my bookings (up until Sunday) by my script:

```
$sql = "SELECT dt, people, c_fname, c_lname, c_phone, c_notes, code 
FROM restaurantbooking_bookings 
WHERE dt BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY 
ORDER BY dt ASC";
```

Note: This works fine... And if I change the line selecting the dates to:

```
WHERE dt BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 DAY
```

This displays my restaurant bookings From Wednesday next until Sunday next.

So my question is why can I not do this for subsequent week i.e.

```
WHERE dt BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 19 DAY
```

This and any later dates will not work... HELP! :)

Comment: what happens with the higher intervals, have you accidentally reversed the order? between requires a specific order else you get no rows `between low_value and high_value` if high is listed first **bam** no rows

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
    WHERE dt  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND 
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 19 DAY)
```

Comment: please post the solution too

Comment: Please explain your solution in the answer.